# Visual Studio C++ - change main.cpp file for each build solution configuration

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I need to change default(main.cpp) file for each build configuration.

> Two cpp files

1. main.cpp - created on project creation time
2. second.cpp

> Two build configurations.

1. Release - compiling main.cpp
2. Custom - *also compiling main.cpp but i need to compile* **second.cpp**

How can i do this? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Right click the file > Properties > General > Exclude from build .  This excludes the file from the build for the currently selected configuration at the top of the dialog.  You can create as many custom configurations as you need.

Comment: @RichardCritten Thank you very much!

Comment: @RichardCritten Seems like your comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer provided by Richard Critten:

```
Right click the file > Properties > General > Exclude from build
```

This excludes the file from the build for the currently selected configuration at the top of the dialog. You can create as many custom configurations as you need.